# Accelerometer sensor sometimes returns zero for all the three axis

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope

Currently, i am developing an application to collect the accelerometer and gyroscope sensor data and saved them into a file. I am using the alarm manager to schedule the alarm to be fired every fifteen minutes and once the alarm fired it will start to collect the data in the background.

But the problem that i had faced is that sometimes the accelerometer sensor return me zero for all the three axis. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here is part of my IntentService class codes:

```
public class SaveSensorDataService extends IntentService{

     private SensorManager sensorManager;
     private Sensor accelerometerSensor;
     private Sensor gyroscopeSensor;
     private float[] gyroscopeValues = new float[3];
     private float[] accelerometerValues = new float[3];
     private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
                accelerometerValues = sensorEvent.values;
            }
            if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
               gyroscopeValues = sensorEvent.values;
            } 
         }

         @Override
         public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    }; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
          //Called by the system when the service is first created.
          //SensorManager
          sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
          accelerometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
          //Gyroscope Sensor
          gyroscopeSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
          sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
          sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, gyroscopeSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        try {   //Wait for the sensor data from the callback methods.
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (writeFile()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Succefully saved into file.");
            sendNotification();
            Log.i(TAG, "Wakelock released.");
            completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
     }
     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();

          //unregister the listener.
          sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
     }
}
```

Comment: The device was accelerating upwards at 9.8 m/s^2, canceling gravity?  Is it returning all 0s once, or for a long period of time?

Comment: The device is putting on the table without moving. I schedule it to write the data into a file every fifteen minutes once the alarm fired. But don't know why the accelerometer data will sometimes be zeros for all the three axis.

Comment: You can recall function when you get zero,once or twice time.

Comment: How to recall the function? I am using the callback method onSensorChanged to get the sensor values and saved it into file by calling the writeToFile() function.